# Finding Bicycle Parts

Tags: maintenance

How would I find bicycle parts cross-referencing make and model? I own a Dept. Store Schwinn Dual Sport (GTX), and before I begin dismantling the bottom bracket for servicing, (it's been 3 years since I bought this bike brand new with a lot of exercise mileage); I would like to have the parts in hand. I've searched and Googled ad nauseam and I find nothing. Also, I can't find a parts blowup specific to my make and model, (just the generic drawings in the so-called Schwinn User Manual....which is probably used for other models). Why is it so hard to find this information? What purchasing source do the bike shops use?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, parts are somewhat standardized. For example, bottom brackets only come in a few [types](http://www.bikeradar.com/us/gear/article/complete-guide-to-bottom-brackets-36660/) and different size.

Given its a recent department store bike, you likely have a standard square taper bottom bracket with ISO threading. You can take the [relevant](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-bottombrackets.html) [measurements](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/bbsize.html) (spindle length, shell width, etc.), but the easiest way for bottom brackets is either read them off the existing bottom bracket (usually labeled) or take it to a bike shop so they can measure it quickly and give you a new one.

As for other parts, you can usually identify them by what family of parts they belong to if they're in the drivetrain (# of speeds and manufacturer), or measure them for things like seatposts or handlebars (which are also standardized, e.g. road bikes use some sizes, mountain others).